# Java add progressbar for current Thread

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

How can I add a `progressbar` that would show how much time will it take untill the current process in done?
I do know how to construct and use a `progressbar`, in simple ways, but I do not know how to bound them with a process.

For example when I click a button, I would like to open a jfilechooser, and this may take some time. I want the user to know that the app did not crash and to give an idea of how much time will it take until the jfilechooser appears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Opening `jfilechooser` takes a lot of time? Or do you mean opening the actual file and processing it in background thread? If the latter, simply update `JProgressBar` once in a while from that thread (remember about thrad safety). BTW please tag your question with [tag:swing].

Comment: [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) seems like a right choice here.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz `jfilechooser` was only an example, because at the moment, I do have a problem with it, takes up to 30 sec to open at the first button click.Then at the second try, drops to 3 sec. But anyway I needed to assign a progressbar to my program because it's a large one with 3d graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, when dealing with classes you didn't write, it's not that easy to link the progress bar with the actual progress.

If you'd like to bind it with a progress of some task, here are the steps:

1. Assign a thread to the time-consuming task
2. Use a static field in the parent class as the progress you've accomplished in your task. (may be counter from 1 to 100)
3. Every specific period (1 sec) you check that static field and set the progress bar with it.
4. Inside your task, you divide your long process into solid steps (i.e. opening a file, processing, preparing extracted data ...etc).
5. After every solid step, update the static field in the parent class with the progress so far.

Make sure to regulate the process of writing and reading the static field using semaphores.

Comment: Will be a difficult job, but I think I got the idea. Thank you

Comment: You might wanna have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html